# Xna c# class error

Tags: c#, xna

I'm making a Fade Animation for my game and I got a class named LoadContent and I then wrote:

```
public override void LoadContent (ContentManager Content, Texture2D image, string text, Vector2 position)
{
        base.LoadContent(Content, image, text, position);
        increase = false;
        fadeSpeed = 1.0f;
        defaultTime = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1);
        timer = defaultTime;
        activateValue = 0.0f;
        stopUpdating = false;
        defaultAlpha = alpha;
}
```

but I'm getting a error, I tried to remove override but it doesn't help and tried to change the public to private just to see if it worked but it didn't here is the error:

> 'Xnaplatformer.FadeAnimation.LoadContent(Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content.ContentManager,
>   Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics.Texture2D, string,
>   Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Vector2)': cannot override inherited member
>   'Xnaplatformer.Animation.LoadContent(Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content.ContentManager,
>   Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics.Texture2D, string,
>   Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Vector2)' because it is not marked virtual,
>   abstract, or override C:\Users\Mike\documents\visual studio
>   2013\Projects\Xnaplatformer\Xnaplatformer\Xnaplatformer\FadeAnimation.cs      Xnaplatformer

Answer (score 0):

First of all LoadContent in your code snipet is not a class. It is a method.
And as you asking about LoadContent method a think you trying override Game.LoadContent in custom game class. Mark it as
**protected override**, couse LoadContent in Game is protected too.

I hope this example help you understand how it works:

```
class A
{
    public virtual void DoSome1() // can be overriden couse marked as virtual
    {
        // logic for class A
    }
    public void DoSome2(); // should be overriden couse it abstract method that have no body by default; any abstartc method makes class abstract too
    public void DoSome3() // can not be overriden: 1. not abstract; 2. not virtual
    {
        // logic for class A
    }
    protected virtual void DoSome4() // protected stil can be overriden; this method visible only inside class A and B
    {
        // logic for class A
    }
    private virtual void DoSome5() // virtual modifier is invalid couse private stil can not be overriden; visible only inside class A
    {
        // logic for class A
    }
}

class B : A
{
    public override void DoSome1() // use override keyword to re-define method from base class
    {
        // logic for class B
    }
    public override void DoSome2() // as A.DoSome2() is abstract you should override it B, or B also became abstratct
    {
        // logic for class B
    }
    new public void DoSome3() // this method not override A.DoSome3(), this is totally new method
    {
        // logic for class B
    }
    protected void DoSome4() // override A.DoSome4(); note: it also marked as protected
    {
        // logic for class B
    }
}
```